# SQL Server SPID is sleeping or runnable but nothing happens for over an hour

Tags: sql-server, ssis, iseries-navigator

I use SQL Server 2012 BI edition.

I've executed two SQL Agent Jobs that run SSIS packages. Historically, the jobs have been running absolutely fine. Today, the jobs just stopped/hanged just before completing step 1 out of 4.

I've run `sp_who2` and nothing is blocking anything. What can I do to "awake" my jobs? Details of `sp_who2`:

- Status   sleeping
- BlkBy      .
- Command  AWAITING COMMAND
- CPUTime  131276
- DiskIO   607734
- LastBatch    01/12/2017 15:55

The jobs have not failed yet but have not done anything for over an hour.

CPU and RAM do not indicate much activity.

**Solution:**
It feels iSeries AS/400 (IBM) has corrupted .net framework. Reinstalling .net framework fixed an issue. I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you can look up the [last query by SPID](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1799/identify-last-statement-run-for-a-specific-sql-server-session/) and/or see the `percent_complete` and `wait_type` columns in `sys.dm_exec_requests`.  Maybe there will be some additional info that helps your troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks DMason. I've tried it but no queries were returned.

Comment: Does `sys.dm_exec_requests` show any open transactions?  (`open_transaction_count` > 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels iSeries AS/400 (IBM) has corrupted .net framework. Reinstalling .net framework fixed the issue.